# How to know if connection to Database is using SSL or not

Tags: php, ssl, mysqli

I'm using mysqli on PHP to connect to a mysql database. The database have open connection both with ssl and not.
I have produced this code:

```
$db = mysqli_init();
$db->ssl_set(NULL, NULL,'rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem',NULL,NULL);
$db->real_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
$res = $db->query('SHOW TABLES;');
print_r ($res);
$db->close();
```

The output I get it's pretty fine, I get what I want, but I don't understand if my connection is goin out with SSL or not.
If I change the cert name to xyzrds-combined-ca-bundle.pem, it keeps working with no errors... so I guess it just switch on no-ssl when the cert fail.

Any clue on how I can know if I'm connected with SSL or not?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The manual says that if SSL connect fails, then real_connect should fail. But it seems it doesnt. Just by chance, what if you add this line above your code? `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Thanks for the info, it gave me better info, but nothing relative to what I was using, the solution proposed as answer worked fine.Ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure SSL for each client, so you can have SSL and NON SSL connections the same time.

You can chech if SSL is configured by sending the following command: `mysql> show variables like '%ssl%';`

The output should look like this:

```
+---------------+----------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                            |
+---------------+----------------------------------+
| have_openssl  | YES                              |
| have_ssl      | YES                              |
| ssl_ca        | /etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem           |
| ssl_capath    |                                  |
| ssl_cert      | /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem       |
| ssl_cipher    |                                  |
| ssl_key       | /etc/mysql/server-key.pem        |
+---------------+----------------------------------+
```

You can set the following configuration to your mYSQL user:

`REQUIRE X509:` a valid SSL certificate must be used

`REQUIRE ISSUER / REQUIRE SUBJECT:` a SSL certificate with specific ISSUER and/or SUBJECT must be used

`REQUIRE SSL:` the connection is forced to use SSL, authentification can be done by password or valid SSL certificate

With the following comamnd you can check the status of your connected clients:

`mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';`

Output should look like this:

```
+---------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name | Value              |
+---------------+--------------------+
| Ssl_cipher    | DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA | 
+---------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: It would be nice if you add PHP code for this check, because the OP apparently wants to make their code fail if no SSL is used.

Comment: Don´t realy know what you mean. The commands are pure SQL which can be send as query. But as far as you should execute these tests from the host system of the database (on which PHP might not be installed) sending from the commandline makes more sence.

Comment: Take a look at this page https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/06/22/setting-up-mysql-ssl-and-secure-connections/ point `Establish secure connection from PHP` may be helpful for you

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael, the solution worked, I got  this array on wrong certificate (even if the connection was good)
([0] => Ssl_cipher    [Variable_name] => Ssl_cipher    [1] =>    [Value] =>)

and this Array if che certificate was good
Array
([0] => Ssl_cipher  [Variable_name] => Ssl_cipher  [1] => AES256-SHA  [Value] => AES256-SHA)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi what if I want to check if ssl connection is using `TSLv1.2` or not?

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40176), here is a quick code to check whether your connection is SSL-based or not:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher'");
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
if(empty($row['Value']))
{
    echo 'No SSL';
}
```

Comment: exactly, just added in the question above so it's more easy to get

Comment: You need to check for $row['Value'], where Value is written with a capital V.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MySQL 5.7.5 or later you can [use perfomance_schema](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/02/23/mysql-connection-using-ssl-or-not/)

```
SELECT sbt.variable_value AS tls_version,  t2.variable_value AS cipher, 
         processlist_user AS user, processlist_host AS host 
FROM performance_schema.status_by_thread  AS sbt 
   JOIN performance_schema.threads AS t ON t.thread_id = sbt.thread_id 
   JOIN performance_schema.status_by_thread AS t2 ON t2.thread_id = t.thread_id 
WHERE sbt.variable_name = 'Ssl_version' AND t2.variable_name = 'Ssl_cipher' 
ORDER BY tls_version
```

Yields

```
+-------------+--------------------+------+---------------+
| tls_version | cipher             | user | host          |
+-------------+--------------------+------+---------------+
| TLSv1.1     | DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA | root | 192.168.1.100 |
+-------------+--------------------+------+---------------+
```