# How to verify TLSv1.2 SSL database connection in Python 3.x (sqlalchemy)

Tags: ssl, sqlalchemy, wireshark, tls1.2, wireshark-dissector

Currently I'm using `mysql_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine()` in my Python code to connect with a MySQL database, I did some reading online, it says that `TLSv1.2` is the default connection version, but I want to find a way to verify this, can I do something like query something from the database and check the version it returns is `v1.2` or not?

Here's what I triedby following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317242/how-to-know-if-connection-to-database-is-using-ssl-or-not):
I queried from MySQL workbench `show variables like '%ssl%';` and it returns:

```
Variable_name  Value
have_openssl    YES
have_ssl        YES
ssl_ca         xxx
ssl_capath  
ssl_cert       xxx
ssl_cipher      xxxxxxxx
ssl_crl 
ssl_crlpath 
ssl_key         xxx
```

This inspired me to try `show variables like '%tls_version%';` and it returns:

```
Variable_name         Value
tls_version          TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

I thought it will only return TLSv1.2, does anyone know why it returns three versions? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Update: I read online we can use Wireshark to verify tlsv1.2, can someone point me in the direction of a comprehensive guide regarding how to achieve this with Wireshark in Python please?

Comment: A start would be to execute `show status like 'ssl_cipher';`. If it returns a value like `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384` then you might be able to deduce if it corresponds to TLS 1.2.

Comment: @GordThompson Hi thanks, is there any page I can read about this? I'm not very familiar with this, I tried to query `show status like 'ssl_cipher'` from MySQL workbench but nothing returns. Anything I can do from Pthon script to verify this?